# Android - Launch Swarm (4sq) intent in specific place

Tags: android, foursquare

I want to launch in my android app a intent that open the [Swarm app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foursquare.robin&hl=es_419) in a specific shop (I known the 4sq id previously)

There is no documentation for the Swarm api, only for 4sq but I don't want to integrate the SDK or communicate with the API. I need launch the Swarm app in the shop to allow the user make the check-in

Thanks a lot!